# JPA Hibernate not firing JOIN Query

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 Database tables. There entities are designed as :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CityTable")
public class CityTable implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="city_id")
    private int cityId;

    private int addedBy;

    @Column(name="city_name")
    private String cityName;



    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="city_id", referencedColumnName="city_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private List<VirtualCityMapping> virtualCity;

    . getters and setters
```

}

**Second**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="virtualCityMapping")
public class VirtualCityMapping implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private VirtualCityMappingEmbedded key; 

    public VirtualCityMapping() {
    }

    public VirtualCityMappingEmbedded getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(VirtualCityMappingEmbedded key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "VirtualCityMapping [key=" + key + "]";
    }


}
```

It is using embedded key, which as defined below

```
@Embeddable
public class VirtualCityMappingEmbedded implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="city_id",nullable=false)
    private int cityId;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private int virtualCityId;

    public int getCityId() {
        return cityId;
    }

    public void setCityId(int cityId) {
        this.cityId = cityId;
    }

    public int getVirtualCityId() {
        return virtualCityId;
    }

    public void setVirtualCityId(int virtualCityId) {
        this.virtualCityId = virtualCityId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "VirtualCityMappingEmbedded [cityId=" + cityId + ", virtualCityId=" + virtualCityId + "]";
    }


}
```

**my City Repo**

public interface CityRepository extends JpaRepository{

```
List<CityTable> findByCityIdIn(List<Integer> stateId);
```

}

My Issue is when I am calling this Repo function, two single queries are getting fired instead of JOin query.

How should I change my code?

Comment: what is the query you are seeing multiple times?

Comment: one for each table. One is select * from CityTable where city_id IN (), second is select * from virtualTable where city_id = ?